# Simple Integration Identity

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Prove, by sketching the region of integration and interchanging the order of integration, that
>
> $$ \int_a^x \int_a^{\xi} f(s) ds d\xi = \int_a^x (x-s)f(s)ds $$

This is probably quite simple but I'm having brain freeze right now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the integration region is a triangular region with vertices at $(a,a)$, $(a,x)$, and $(x,x)$ in the $s-\xi$-plane.

Thus, if the inner integral is on $s$, we see that for any fixed $\xi$, $s$ begins at $a$ and ends at $\xi$.

If the inner integral is on $\xi$, we see that for any fixed $s$, $\xi$ begins at $s$ and ends at $x$.

Therefore, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\int_a^x \int_a^\xi f(s)\,ds\,d\xi&=\int_a^x \int_s^x f(s)\,d\xi\,ds\\\\
&=\int_a^x f(s)\left(\int_s^x (1)\,d\xi\right)\,ds\\\\
&=\int_a^x f(s)(x-s)\,ds
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Thank you. Very straightforward after all!

Comment: Andrew.  You're welcome.  My pleasure.  And pleased to hear that you have it now!  -Mark